# Il pousse plus de choses dans un jardin que n'en sème le jardinier

Tags: sens, proverbes

What is the **n'** for in this sentence?

> Il pousse plus de choses dans un jardin que n'en sème le jardinier

If I remove that **n'**, will that be bad grammar?
Or will it fine grammar but mean something different?

> Il pousse plus de choses dans un jardin qu'en sème le jardinier